# Android launch applications detail page

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on an application where I list the installed applications with the package manager. I can get the package name of the item clicked, but I'd like to then launch the details screen based on the package. So for instance if Dolphin Browser were selected in the list, you would then see the following image. How can I do this?

[image]

**Final solution set your target as [Gingerbread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Gingerbread) API level 9 and set your min as API level 7**

```
final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Intent intent = new Intent();
if (apiLevel >= 9) {
    //TODO get working on gb
    //Toast.makeText(SDMove.this, "Gingerbread Not Currently Supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                             Uri.parse("package:" + pli.pkg.packageName)));
} else {
    final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? "pkg" : "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
    intent.putExtra(appPkgName, pli.pkg.packageName);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a fully working app with a `ListActivity` that lists all installed apps. When you click a package name, it opens the app details.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Intent for getting installed apps.
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    // Get installed apps
    List<ResolveInfo> appList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    // Make new list for package names and fill the list.
    List<String> packageNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : appList) {
        packageNameList.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
    }

    // Set the list adapter.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple, packageNameList));
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    // Get the TextView that was clicked.
    TextView view = (TextView)v;

    // Get the text from the TextView.
    String packageName = (String)view.getText();

    // Open AppDetails for the selected package.
    showInstalledAppDetails(packageName);
}

public void showInstalledAppDetails(String packageName) {
    final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    if (apiLevel >= 9) {
        intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    } else {
        final String appPkgName = (apiLevel == 8 ? "pkg" : "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName");

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }

    // Start Activity
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Remember to have **main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView  
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="No apps installed"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and **simple.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</TextView>
```

in your **layout** folder. Hope this works :)

Comment: Is there a manifest permission or something for this? i keep getting force closes with anything i try i just tried your method set it to something simple such as deskclock. I put your method in then ran showInstalledAppDetails("com.android.deskclock"); but no matter what i try it force closes i'm running project elite gb on a rooted d1 but the app i have set to 2.2 as my min sdk but no idea why i force close everytime

Comment: I got it to run on my 2.2 emulator, but when I tried "com.android.deskclock" I got "Exception when retrieving package: com.android.deskclock". Try another app, like "com.android.settings", that worked in the emulator. It is very important that the package name is right :) If you don't get it to work, you could post the stacktrace from LogCat.

Comment: Yea just made a new project with 2.3 as the target this method force closes but the code below worked with 2.3 like you said but i need it on 2.2 since i'm writing this app for a 2.2 rom. Anyway posting the logcat in a second didn't see anything really in there but maybe you will

Comment: Java Code
http://pastebin.com/cgjrAx2A

Log Cat
http://pastebin.com/P0e9XR4t
error is at lines 98 and 99

Comment: I couldn't get the method above to work on my 2.3.3 phone, but on both the 2.2 and 2.3 emulator it worked :S But when I tried the first method on my phone it worked perfectly.. I'll have to look at it tomorrow

Comment: yea it's working on 2.2 but i'm on 2.3 now and it's not working :/ i have an if statement currently checking the api level it just toast gingerbread if the api level is 9 or above and your code in there if under 9 which it is working there just need to get it going now on gb as well

Comment: It looks like the first answer is the only working method for api level 9 and up, while the others need to use the second answer...

Comment: so it seems not possible to have the 2.2 set as the applications min and target and be able to open this on both 2.2 and 2.3?

Comment: Well i set the target to 2.3 meaning i was using the 2.3 sdk with my app i then went in the manifest and set the min to 7 and it actually works ha well putting updating my post to include the final code thanks for all the help accept and vote coming you were very helpful lots of ideas

Comment: @khellang how to get the result whether the user click on force stop button or not??

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:your.package.here")));
```

And replace "package:your.package.here" with the real package you want to view...

Comment: This answer is much better :)

Comment: also, make sure to include the build variant if any. 
ex : Uri.parse("package:your.package.here."+BuildConfig.FLAVOR)

Answer (score 3):

To launch the app info setting for your app.

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("package")
        .opaquePart(getPackageName())
        .build();
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, uri));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way to do it, this is a generic answer using build infos from your app. You have to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and build the right `URI` for your app.

```
  // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

You can use it from a snackbar for example.

```
Snackbar.make(
    findViewById(R.id.activity_layout),
    "snackbar text",
    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("Settings", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(
                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    })
            .show();
```